# Issue about nuget package in UWP developing

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, nuget

I am a newer to UWP programming using VS2017.

I share one of my UWP project to my friend but it can not run properly on his computer.
But it seems that some resource in my project references to my local path!
Note that **"C:\Users\zkb22.nuget\packages\"** is a path in my computer, not my friend's.

The error message(ON MY FRIEND'S VS) is as following.

> The package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights with version 1.0.0 could not
>   be found in C:\Users\zkb22.nuget\packages. Run a NuGet package
>   restore to download the package.

Comment: Have you ran package restore by right clicking the solution and selecting restore package?

Comment: It seems like you've copied it with the `bin` and `obj` folders which contain compiled app. He should delete them and then `Build > Clean Solution`. Then the app should work as expected.

Comment: I've already deleted the bin and obj folders.

Comment: Can you share the project with me? or send me an email at karann[at]microsoft[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and then install the required Nuget package, this worked for me.